# co-occurance matrix for hand calculation

Tags: sql, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I have table with user purchase events. I want to create a co-occurence matrix to compute loglikehood ratio using the formula mentioned [here](http://tdunning.blogspot.com/2008/03/surprise-and-coincidence.html). I am first trying to create the 2X2 table: Can some help with the calcuation. Below is sample data. How do I create 2X2 co-occurence table for item 1&3(I have a table below. Want to validate if it is correct)

```
user_id,item_id
1,3
2,4
3,4
2,3
3,2
1,1
2,1

user_id, item_id
1, {1,3}
2, {4,3,1}
3, {2,4}

Item to Item co-occurence output(I want to confirm if this is correct)  
purchased item both 1 & 3 : 2 
purchased item 1 but not 3 : 0
purchased item 3 but not 1 : 0
neither item 1 or 3 : 5
       | 3   |not3
---------------
     1 |2    |0  
 not1  |0    |5
```

Comment: I can't figure out what the "1"s and "3"s and "0"s are referring to.  If you have *a* table, why are you showing two with similar information?

Comment: updated the comment. two table to show steps for calculation